# Как верно принимать ответ от php/ajax

Tags: javascript, php

Отправляю запрос к php

```
fetch('/ajax/', {body: FormAdd(ms), method: 'POST'})
    .then(r => r.json()).then(d => eval(d))
    .catch(er => alert('Не удалось подключиться к серверу'));
```

Отдаю ответ от php

```
die(json_encode("alert('sdf')"))
```

Вопрос в том, отдаем в ответ "alert('sdf')", в js принимаю eval(d).

Собственно чтобы js выполнить, что в ответе, оборачиваю в eval.

Собственно как отдать ответ так, чтобы выполнить js не оборачивая в eval

Comment: А чем вам eval не угодил?

Comment: Хз, пишут что как без eval возможно обойтись. Хотелось бы узнать как это?

Comment: Кто пишут — тех и спросите, не?

Comment: Однако очень странным является сам тот факт, что вы вообще зачем-то отдаёте ответ в виде js-кода

Comment: +1  зачем отдавать js? Тем более с помощью js идёт запрос на сервер. Значит есть возможность обработать ответ в виде, например, json

Comment: На сервере отдать sdf без alert, а на клиенте как раз сделать alert response

Comment: К примеру сервер отдает список новостей, мне этот список формировать массивом, в в js писать шаблон, затем при получении ответа пропускать список через цикл с шаблоном? Не проще отдать html код и выполнить вставку в html?

Comment: Как ты вообще связал то, что ты отдаешь js  и то, что ты планируешь рендерить что-то? Две перпендикулярных проблемы.. Логика хде?

Comment: А вообще - зависит от задачи и от наличия разрабов. Если в наличии только бэкендеры или человек не умеет во фронтенд - да, проще отдавать html с бэка...... Если по сети надо отдавать легковесное что-то и не нагружать сервер и к тому-же использовать реактивные библиотеки - то отдавать данные, а на клиенте перерисовывать дом дерево. это в разы быстрее

Comment: По современной модели на сервере Вы работаете с данными, данные получаете и отдаете (в исключительно редких случаях что-то другое может быть возвращено). Клиентская часть у Вас отвечает за взаимодействие с пользователем и отрисовку шаблонов. НЕ получайте никогда на клиент куски HTML/JS, если ожидаете обработку данных! Это плохая практика.

Comment: Более того, Ваш `eval(d)` – здоровенная дыра. Получается, можно подсунуть на сервер как-то кусок кода с XSS, и тогда будет весело)

Comment: Можно тут поподробнее? Не совсем понимаю, как это делают. Что бы иметь хотя бы представление об этом.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar, если _можно подсунуть на сервер как-то кусок кода_ - то eval - это меньшая из проблем.

Comment: @Grundy Ну на сервере JS код - это ничего страшного (если это не node.js, конечно). Но вообще да, если до такого доходит, страшно представить, что там ещё написано с проблемами безопасности...

Comment: @VladimirGonchar, имелось ввиду, что если есть доступ к серверу - то он может что угодно отправить, не важно будет на клиенте eval или нет

Answer (score 1):

Можете просто тэг `script` зааппендить в документ без аякса и JSON-a

```js
var s = document.createElement("script");
// сюда вставляете урл на PHP-файл, котороый формирует js-код
s.src = "http://somedomain.com/somescript";
document.head.appendChild.append(s);
```